The proxy server is refusing connections (JMeter recording)
I am trying to load test for my web application. I followed all the steps as per JMeter guide. After that enable proxy server also using port number 8888.
Please take a look my proxy server description in Firefox:

Please check my JMETER Configuration

Output after did all configuration after this config
I can not load the any website

I installed all ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate on my browser

But still am facing same proxy issue
I am new for JMETER load testing, hope you guys will help to solve this problem.

You need to really start the JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder first, to wit click this button:

Also you will need to set network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost to true in Firefox
Be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates

No I am facing  The connection has timed out

It's another issue, we cannot help you without seeing your jmeter.log file preferably with JMeter debug logging enabled for the HTTP(S) test script recorder.  Any chance you're behind a corporate proxy? If this is the case - you need to configure JMeter to use this upstream proxy.
